# CodeIgniter not loading my lang file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have controller and there is a function which calls `password`. There I have email form:

```
        $this->email->from('system@domain.us', "domain.us");
        $this->email->to($user_data['email']); 
        $this->email->subject(lang('users_validations_passwordemail_title'));
        $this->email->message(lang('users_validations_passwordemail_hi').", ". ucfirst(strtolower($userInfo[0]['username'])) .lang('users_validations_passwordemail_text'). $user_data['random_string'] ."");   
        $this->email->send();
```

and in the controller contructor function I have:

```
$this->lang->load('controllers', $this->session->userdata('session_lang'));
```

but when I tried to send message I've got this message:

```
Unable to load the requested language file: language/france/email_lang.php
```

so how tu use it? why i've got this error? how to fix it?

BTW - I tried to use `lang('users_validations_passwordemail_title')` simple (not in email form) and that worked for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are loading a file which does not exist. If you have a france language folder, you have to have email_lang.php file in it with your required data. In this case, your required language key

Comment: you are not right mister, I dont want to load email_lang.php, couse i have loaded `$this->lang->load('controllers', $this->session->userdata('session_lang'));` before

Comment: How can you skip CodeIgniter core language file? It's default CodeIgniter language file which HAS to be loaded :)

Comment: and you was right, i had to create email_lang.php file becouse it was necessary :)