# Site throwing error on live server with language class while works on Xampp: Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have my language script running absolutely fine in Xampp... It translates to other languages..

I just happened to upload it to live server and I can't seem to fix an error which was never their in Xampp.

> Unable to load the requested language file: language/italian/homepage_italian_lang.php

It keeps throwing that error. I have checked that language files are in place. This is happening for all languages.

I have to delete cookies and then come back to homepage because of session..

Works fine on Xampp though,,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896938/unable-to-load-the-requested-language-file-language-en-form-validation-lang-php    and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122394/codeigniter-not-loading-my-lang-file    and https://ellislab.com/forums/archive/viewthread/223074

Comment: Check your class and file names make sure only first letter is upper case on controllers and models etc.

Comment: @wolfgang1983.. Solved.. Controller and model first letter upper cases were already fine but I just discovered Xampp didn't care about upper case of language files and executed the code.. While in Live server didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a wild guess, but I would check if XAMPP and the online PHP are both the same version. Different versions can cause unexpected problems that are hard to figure out.